# jdbc. preparedStatement incrementing value in sql

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have 2 tables in database
    `authors (author_id, first_name, last_name);
      books (book_id, book_title, book_author_id);`
book_author_id is fk to author_id

and when im trying to fill database for tests

```
    private static BookDao dao = new BookDaoImpl(new DBConnection("liquibase/liquibase.properties"));
    private static Author author1 = new Author(1, "Joshua", "Bloch");
    private static Author author2 = new Author(2, "Robert", "Martin");
    private static Book book1 = new Book(1, "Effective Java", 1);
    private static Book book2 = new Book(2, "Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases", 1);
    private static Book book3 = new Book(3, "Clean code", 2);
    private static Book book4 = new Book(4, "Clean Architecture", 2);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void fillDataBases() throws DAOException {
        authorDao.save(author1);
        authorDao.save(author2);
        dao.save(book1);
        dao.save(book2);
        dao.save(book3);
        dao.save(book4);
    }
```

receiving this log

```
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - starting to check if author exists in database
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for finding author by name
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'SELECT * from authors WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?', parameters : ['Joshua','Bloch']
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - author doesn't exist in database. you can save new author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for saving new author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'insert into authors(first_name, last_name) values(?,?)', parameters : ['Joshua','Bloch']
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - new author saved
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - starting to check if author exists in database
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for finding author by name
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'SELECT * from authors WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ?', parameters : ['Robert','Martin']
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - author doesn't exist in database. you can save new author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for saving new author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'insert into authors(first_name, last_name) values(?,?)', parameters : ['Robert','Martin']
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - new author saved
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for finding book by title and author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'SELECT * from books WHERE book_title = ? AND book_author_id = ?', parameters : ['Effective Java',1]
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - book doesn't exist in database. we can save new book
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for saving new book
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - book title Effective Java book author's id 1
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'insert into books(book_title, book_author_id) values(?,?)', parameters : ['Effective Java',1]
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - new book saved
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for finding book by title and author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'SELECT * from books WHERE book_title = ? AND book_author_id = ?', parameters : ['Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases',1]
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - book doesn't exist in database. we can save new book
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for saving new book
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - book title Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases book author's id 1
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'insert into books(book_title, book_author_id) values(?,?)', parameters : ['Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases',2]
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - new book saved
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for finding book by title and author
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'SELECT * from books WHERE book_title = ? AND book_author_id = ?', parameters : ['Clean code',2]
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - book doesn't exist in database. we can save new book
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - creating statement for saving new book
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - book title Clean code book author's id 2
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - sql : 'insert into books(book_title, book_author_id) values(?,?)', parameters : ['Clean code',3]
2019-05-29 23:48:26 - (conn=1118) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myapp`.`books`, CONSTRAINT `fk_author_books` FOREIGN KEY (`book_author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`author_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

as you can see preparedStatement increment book_author_id by 1 each time when im saving book into database, but it shouldn't do this. can you please explain why this happening and how to fix this. if i will use just database console sql queries it will work, but if using prepared statement got this problem.
Added book dao save method

```
 public int save(Book book) throws DAOException {
        int i = 0;
        if (!isExists(book.getTitle(), book.getAuthorId())) {
            String sql = "insert into books(book_title, book_author_id) values(?,?)";
            try (Connection connection = dbConnection.getConnection()) {
                logger.trace("creating statement for saving new book");

                try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                    statement.setString(1, book.getTitle());
                    statement.setLong(2, book.getId());
                    logger.trace("book title " + book.getTitle() + " book author's id " + book.getAuthorId());
                    logger.trace(statement);
                    i = statement.executeUpdate();
                    logger.trace("new book saved");
                    logger.trace(connection.getMetaData());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                throw new DAOException("cannot save new book to database", e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new DAOException("book " + book.getTitle() + " by author "
                    + book.getAuthorId() + " already exists in database");
        }
        return i;
    }
```

isExists same method with select * from books where book_title = 'title' and book_author_id = id
return true if exists and false if doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you look at your code sample: you're setting the second parameter of your prepared statement to the book id, instead of the book_author_id.

Your code:

```
                statement.setLong(2, book.getId());
```

but it should be

```
                statement.setLong(2, book.getBookAuthorId()); // assuming the getter is called that way
```

as a matter of fact- the ID of the books is incrementing by one for each